# configure different hostname for every contain when use docker compose swarm？

Tags: docker, docker-compose, dockerfile, docker-swarm

docker-compose.yml

```
services:
    {{ app }}{{ env_id }}-{{stage_name}}:
      image: "{{ registry_url }}/{{ app }}-{{ stage_name }}:{{ tag }}"
      ports:
        - {{ port }}:3000
      volumes:
        - /var/log/{{ app }}/logs:/app/logs
      networks:
        - net{{ env_id }}
      hostname: "{{contain_name}}"
      logging:
        driver: syslog
        options:
          tag: "{{ app }}"
      stop_grace_period: 20s
      healthcheck:
        test: ["CMD", "curl", "-f", "http://localhost:3000/version"]
        interval: 5s
        timeout: 10s
        retries: 3
        start_period: 5s
      deploy:
        replicas: 4
        update_config:
          parallelism: 1
          order: start-first
          failure_action: rollback
          monitor: 15s
        rollback_config:
          order: start-first
        restart_policy:
          condition: any
          delay: 5s
        resources:
          limits:
           memory: 7G

networks:
  net{{ env_id }}:
    name: {{ app }}{{ env_id }}_network
```

use the docker-compose.yml,I can get a swarm stack and four contains, but contains have same hostname,I want they named like
"contain_name1
contain_name2
contain_name3
contain_name4"
How to do it?

Comment: If you delete the `hostname:` lines, the containers will believe their hostnames are their hex-digit container IDs.  You usually don't need to set this at all, though.

Comment: I want to set hostnames have same prefix

Comment: Why?  That only affects what the container thinks its own hostname is, and that's almost never visible anywhere.  I tend to ignore `hostname:` entirely.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, this functionality is not yet supported. https://github.com/docker/swarmkit/issues/1242
Kubernetes can resolve this problem by using StatefulSet. https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/workloads/controllers/statefulset/